# Covariant Derivative definition question.

Tags: differential-geometry

First time learning Covariant Derivatives.

One step in the definition does not make sense to me.

In the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Coordinate_description) description, they say that

> The covariant derivative of a basis vector along a basis vector is again a vector and so can be expressed as a linear combination $\Gamma^{k}e_k$.

Here is my formulation of the covariant derivative (very similar to wikiapedia).

Let $(x^i)$ be a coordinate system on space $M$ and $(e_j)$ be basis vectors on $M$.

Let $u = \sum_j u^j e_j$  be a general vector field with components $u^j$, then

$$\frac{du}{dx^i} = \sum_{j}\left( e_j \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^i} + u^j\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial x^i}\right).$$

Now wikipedia says (in Einstein notation for the RHS) we can write $$\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial x^i} = \Gamma_{ji}^k e_k$$

Here is what I don't understand.

1. When you take a derivative, are you not in a different tangent space? How can you write an object expressed in the basis vectors of the tangent space $\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial x^i}$ in terms of basis vectors of the original space $e_k$?
2. Also when one change indices of the above (swap $k$ and $j$) to

$$\frac{du}{dx^i} =  e_j \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^i} + u^j\frac{\partial e_j}{\partial x^i} = e_j \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^i} + u^k\frac{\partial e_k}{\partial x^i} = e_j \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^i} + u^k\Gamma_{ki}^j e^j$$

How is the $k$ defined inside $u = u^je_j$? Is it $1 \leq k \leq j$?

Comment: you should consider the std connection of $\Bbb R^n$ and the other induced on subspaces $M$ of $\Bbb R^n$ where $M$ isn't necessarily a linear subspace

Comment: I don't follow...

Comment: connection or covariant derivative are the same